# Projected sales value for year in Google Data studio from average performance

Tags: formula, looker-studio

I have a PostGreSql table with following fields and connected to my Google Data Studio report.

```
Date (YYYYMMDD) | Field1 | Field2
```

Fields 1 and 2 are numeric.

I have created a calculated field of Turnover as `Sum(Field1)-Sum(Field2)`.

Now am trying to add an indicator to show the Projected 2018 turnover. It should be calculated as

Monthly average of Turnover for current year `(Values available till date) × 12`

I tried creating another field ProjectedTurnover with formula `Avg(Turnover)*12` with date range as YYYYMM format.

While writting the formula it gives me "re-aggregating metric" error.

I searched various forums to get answer to this and still not able to figure out how should I get my Projected Turnover.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The re-aggregating error is usually because you've used sum() in the turnover field.

Try changing that to

> Field1 - Field2

You can then use

> Avg(Turnover)*365

Comment: Just to be clear, you can't do it by making a monthly aggregated figure and then averaging that. You'd have to do that in your dataset pre-loading to Data Studio